# Mongo-java-driver-3.2 mongoexport

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

How can I do mongoexport from java program? I've googled a lot on this topic but didn't find any good explanations on this problem..
I tried this as a test(if it did work I could dump it via mongo command line)

```
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mongo");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("use market");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("db.fruits.insert({name:\"banana\"})");`
```

But it gave me this

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 25 more
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ please take some time to look.Hope you find this helpful

Comment: @SmashCode ok, but how to do it from java programm?

Comment: Are you just trying to read a collection and outputs in JSON ? Which part of `mongoexport` that you are specifically after ?